# Svelte transition not appling to element of a list when there is only one element left because of if statement

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a list of players from which I can remove a player by clicking a button, to make it more dynamic I added a fly transition when the element is removed, here's the code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';

    let players: string[] = ['Juan', 'John', 'Luis'];
</script>

<div class="overflow-hidden">
    {#if players.length == 0}
        <p>No players</p>
    {:else}
        {#each players as player, playerIndex (player)}
            <div class="flex" out:fly={{ duration: 500, x: '100vw', opacity: 100 }}>
                <span>{player}</span>
                <button
                    on:click={() => {
                        players.splice(playerIndex, 1);
                        players = players;
                    }}
                >
                    Remove
                </button>
            </div>
        {/each}
    {/if}
</div>
```

This works fine except for the last element left, when there is only one element left it doesn't apply the transition to it when it is removed. This is happening because of the if statement, when I remove it it works as expected, but I don't want to remove it since I want to show something else when the list is empty.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code you present doesn't exhibit this problem.  I imagine, though, that your problem is hiding the overflows.  The code you present runs all animations just fine in the Svelte REPL.  Either try messing with the overflow setting (can be turned off then on using animation events) or present code that accurately replicates the problem.

Comment: @JoséRamírez I just updated the question to have the actual code I'm using, I was removing some stuff to simplify it and I realised the thing causing my issue is the `if statement`, when I remove it it works as expected, but I do want to have that conditional rendering, is there a way to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is synchronize the condition of the `{#if}` block with the ending of the animation.  This is done very sveltely, like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';

  let players = ['Juan', 'John', 'Luis'];
  let noPlayers = false;
</script>

<div class="overflow-hidden">
  {#if noPlayers}
    <p>No players</p>
  {:else}
    {#each players as player, playerIndex (player)}
      <div
        class="flex"
        out:fly={{ duration: 500, x: '100vw', opacity: 100 }}
        on:outroend={() => noPlayers = players.length === 0}
      >
        <span>{player}</span>
        <button
          on:click={() => {
            players.splice(playerIndex, 1);
            players = players;
          }}
        >
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    {/each}
  {/if}
</div>
```

### Explanation

1. Declare a Boolean variable for use in the `{#if}` block.
2. Defer the calculation of the Boolean variable's value until the end of the animation using the `on:outroend` event.
3. Let Svelte figure out the rest. ✌️

You can learn about transition event [here](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/transition-events).

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by José Ramires works perfectly in this case, although In my real app I can also add players and I want the transition to apply to the first player added, for that I ran into some issues using Jose's solution so I came up with another solution.

Here's the code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';

    let players: string[] = ['Juan', 'John', 'Luis'];
    let noPlayers = true;

    $: if (players.length > 0) {
        noPlayers = false;
    }
</script>

<div class="overflow-hidden">
    {#if noPlayers}
        <p>No players</p>
    {/if}
    {#each players as player, playerIndex (player)}
        <div
            class="flex"
            out:fly={{ duration: 500, x: '100vw', opacity: 100 }}
            on:outroend={() => {
                noPlayers = players.length == 0;
            }}
        >
            <span>{player}</span>
            <button
                on:click={() => {
                    players.splice(playerIndex, 1);
                    players = players;
                }}
            >
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Now I always render the list of players since when it is empty it doesn't render anything already. I also added an if statement to stop showing the "No players" message when there are one or more players, and then I show the message when the outro ends and if there are no players.